# VB.NET set the assembly-version in one file for all projects in solution (VS2013)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

I want to store the assembly-version in one file for all projects in my solution.
This way it's easier to maintain the configuration.

In C# i can add links to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` in the project and `Drag & Drop` the file-link to the `Properties`.
This way the version is displayed correctly in `Properties` => `Application` => `Assembly Information`.

In VB.Net this is not possible. I can't `Drop` files into `My Project`. But this is the place where the AssemblyInfo.vb has to be placed. If it is stored in an other position, Visual Studio doesn't show it in `My Project` => `Application` => `Assembly Information`.

Comment: Would [ZeroToNine](https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine) enable you to accomplish your goal?

Comment: I did't want to use plugins or something like this, because Visual Studio is able to do it in C#-projects.

Comment: The question is clear now i think. Would be great if you could review it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the link(file) in the project itself by right click `Add existing item...` and `cut & paste` the new link into the `MyProject-Folder`.

Comment: This will move the file. The OP wants to link one file in all VB.NET projects.

Comment: It does work like this, since you can't create a link file directly in this `MyProject-Folder`.

Comment: How to cut & paste the link? The link is only in visual studio and i can't drag and drop it to ´MyProject-Folder´. In c#-projects it is possible, but in vb-projects i can't drop it.

Comment: Mark the file in solution explorer and press `Ctrl+x`. Mark the target folder and press `Ctrl+v`, does that work?

Comment: ´Ctrl+x & Ctrl+v´ moves the link to ´My Project´. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)